# Nokia-X NokiaNotificationMessaging error-> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.nokia.push.PushRegistrar

Tags: android, push-notification, nokiax

Hi i tried NOKIA NOTIFICATION MESSAGING in android but i face the following error

> LOG:

```
04-05 13:43:07.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1042): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 13:43:07.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1042): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.nokia.push.PushRegistrar
04-05 13:43:07.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at com.example.nokiapush.NotificationsManager.<init>(NotificationsManager.java:68)
04-05 13:43:07.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at com.example.nokiapush.NotificationsManager.getInstance(NotificationsManager.java:46)
04-05 13:43:07.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at com.example.nokiapush.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:65)
04-05 13:43:07.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5180)
04-05 13:43:07.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-05 13:43:07.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2031)
04-05 13:43:07.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
04-05 13:43:07.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
04-05 13:43:07.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
04-05 13:43:07.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-05 13:43:07.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-05 13:43:07.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4807)
04-05 13:43:07.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-05 13:43:07.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-05 13:43:07.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
04-05 13:43:07.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:559)
04-05 13:43:07.801: E/AndroidRuntime(1042):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You need to import this class `com.nokia.push.PushRegistrar` into your Android project.

Comment: @ChuongPham I import that in my project already

Comment: Are you sure? Because the error complained that this class is missing. Maybe you're missing the JAR file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are also exporting that library. If you are not exporting, library is only available at build time. Select Build path properties from eclipse (if using that) and from "Order and Export" tab select push jar to be exported. If it is not visible there check that you are exporting private libraries and dependencies.

Make also sure that you are running your app in Android emulator that is having Nokia X image (build target is Nokia X)